# libmodbus : Unable to Poll modbus energy meter having stop bit as 2

Tags: c, embedded, modbus

I am trying to poll n schneider Energymeter in having parity as none and stop bit as 2 using a RS485 to USB converter. I am getting connection timed out error. But when I try to poll the same meter with parity as none and stopbit as 1, I am able to receive the data.

The code snippet I am using to poll the meter is as follows

```
     ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600, 'N', 8, 2);
     modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);
      if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1) {
           printf("Modbus Connection failed: %s", modbus_strerror(errno));
           modbus_free(ctx);
           return -1;
      }
      modbus_set_slave(ctx,2);
      memset(tab_rp_registers, 0, 2 * sizeof(uint16_t));
      rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx,3109,2,tab_rp_registers);
      modbus_close(ctx);
      modbus_free(ctx);
      if (rc != -1) {
      // actions performed

      }
      else {
      free(tab_rp_registers);
      printf("Error str is %s\n",modbus_strerror(errno));
       }
```

Always I am getting the rc as -1 and the Connection timed out error when converting the errno.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are always getting rc as -1 when Stop bits are 2?

Comment: yes and also I am using the stable version of the library i.e 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved on updating the library to 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the shop bits should be 2 with no parity?  The Modbus specification does state that there should be 11 bits per character for RTU which does mean that there should be 2 stop bits when using no parity.  HOWEVER, in my experience, many vendors do not adhere to that rule.  I grabbed the first energy meter manual that I could find from the Schneider web site:

http://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=User+guide&p_File_Name=DOCA0005EN-10.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=DOCA0005EN

On page 47 there is a note "number of stop bits = 1" that appears to apply to all parity modes.

Comment: The new Schneider meter series like em6436h comes with no option to select the stop bit. By default, they are set to stop bit 2 when parity None is selected. So I am in a need to use the stop bit as 2 for the existing setup.